# Can gdb when the service starts, it enters the break

Tags: service, gdb, break

Some open source software is required to start the service, and then attach PID, gdb debugging.

Such services will not start tracking what happens instantly.

I want to track to start the service, while reading the configuration file into the break.When the service can not be started, it enters debug state?

Comment: What OS is your service running on?

Comment: ubuntu linux,It's ceph radosgw